# Divide a set of curves into groups using functional data analysis

Tags: r, functional-programming, grouping, cluster-analysis, curve

I have a dataset containing about 500 curves. In my dataset every row is a curve (which comes from some experimental measurements) and in the columns there are the measurement intervals (I don't think it's important, but intervals are not time measurements but frequency measurements).

[image: curves]

Here you can find the data:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q1F1any8RlCIrn-CcQEzLWyrsyTBCCNv/view?usp=sharing

| curves | t1 | t2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -57.48 | -57.56 |
| 2 | -56.22 | -56.28 |
| 3 | -57.06 | -57.12 |

I want to divide this dataset into 2 - 4 homogeneous groups of curves.
I've seen that there are some packages in R (fda and funHDDC) that allow you to find clusters but I don't know how to create the list with which to start the analysis, and I also don't understand why the initial dataset doesn't fit. How can I transform the data I have into a list suitable for processing with the above packages?
What results should I expect?

Comment: You need to include more information in your question to get a useful answer.  Show us some of your data using `dput()`, or some fake data that has the same structure.

Comment: the complete database is attached and I have added a small excerpt of the same. I have inserted the figure of the curves that I want to divide into groups

Comment: You should post the data in the question in a form that others can use.

Comment: Data should not be shared with a link to external sources since the link may die in the future. Instead, you can use `dput()` to get your data (or a sample).  Additionally, your question "how to create clusters and what to expect?" is a statistics question. Implementations with packages in R is more relevant here, once you tell us what, specifically you want to do.